# Newton mechanics - Inelastic colision

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

A particle $A$ with mass $M_a = 0.001kg$, starts with a velocity of $V_ia = \frac{30m}{s}$, collides with another particle $B$ that is at rest, with mass $M_b = 0.002kg$, and detour it's trajectory in $30º$. In that collision, $30$% of the mechanical energy of the system is lost. Calculate the final velocities of each particle after the colision.

How can I calculate it?!

Here is what I've done so far:

Linear Momentum is going to be conserved, hence:
$$
M_aV_ia = M_aV_fa + M_bV_fb
$$
Since we have a lost of $30$% in our mechanical energy, we get that our final mechanical energy is going to be:
$$
(0.7)(M_a)(V_ia)^2 = M_a(V_fa)^2 + M_b(V_fb)^2
$$

Then I've tried a lot of substitutions with that equations, but always end up getting stucked!

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider the components of velocity along the initial direction of a and the direction perpendicular to that. Apart from that, you have two equations in two unknowns (we know what $V_a$ is), so there is no problem here except algebra.

Comment: Can you solve it? I wanna check how it's done...

Comment: @BrunoReis - separate one of the unknowns in the top equation, substitute that into the second equation, then solve the quadratic.

Comment: That's what I've done

Comment: @BrunoReis - please show your working in the question, what did you get, and what is the problem?

Comment: In addition to suzu hirose answer, i would like to add that the sum of angles at which two balls are deflected is 90 degrees.Use it.

Answer (score 0):

We have four unknowns that we would like to know: $v_{x_1}, v_{y_1}, v_{x_2}, v_{y_2}$. These represent the "horizontal" and "vertical" velocities of the 2 particles after the collision, where "horizontal" indicates parallel to the initial velocity of A and "vertical" orthogonal to that.

Because particle A is deflected by 30 degrees, we know $\frac{v_{y_1}}{v_{x_1}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$, so $v_{y_1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} v_{x_1}$, which implies $v_{y_1}^2 = \frac{1}{3} v_{x_1}^2$.

Now we will use conservation of linear momentum. Let $M = m_1 v_{1, initial }$.

Vertically first: 
$m_1 v_{y_1} + m_2 v_{y_2} = 0$ $\implies$ $v_{y_2} = -\frac{m_1}{m_2} v_{y_1} = -\frac{m_1}{\sqrt{3} m_2} v_{x_1} $, so $v_{y_2}^2 = \frac{m_1^2}{3m_2^2} v_{x_1}^2$

Now horizontally:
$M = m_1 v_{x_1} + m_2 v_{x_2} \implies v_{x_2} = \frac{M-m_1v_{x_1}}{m_2}$

We are now prepared to use the condition on the final energy. Let $E = 0.7  m_1 v_{1,initial}^2$. Then

$E = m_1 (v_{x_1}^2 + v_{y_1}^2) + m_2(v_{x_2}^2+v_{y_2}^2)$, so using the above substitutions, $E = (\frac{4}{3} + \frac{m_1}{3m_2})m_1 v_{x_1}^2 + m_2(\frac{M-m_1v_{x_1}}{m_2})^2 = \frac{M^2}{m_2} - \frac{2 m_1 M}{m_2} v_{x_1} + \frac{4}{3} ( m_1 + \frac{m_1^2}{m2})v_{x_1}^2$.

This is a simple quadratic in $v_{x_1}$. Of the two solutions, pick the one going in the correct direction (i.e. $v_{x_1} > 0$). From here all the rest of the quantities can be found using the equations above.